# How to prevent a list of of tcolorbox'es from repeating the list lable?

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

How do I remove the "repeated" label and box number: "Box 1.1"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage[lf,sfdefault]{FiraSans}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside=mybox]{mybox}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    title={Box~\thetcbcounter:~#2},
    #1,
    halign title=center,
    sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,coltitle=black,titlerule=0pt,
    colbacktitle=lightgray,
    %colback=white,
    drop fuzzy shadow
}


\begin{document}

\tcblistof[\section*]{mybox}{List of boxes}

\section{Blá blá}

\begin{mybox}{A mybox}
That's it.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain the expected output. Is it "Box 1:"  instead of "Box 1.1:"? If so, remove `number within=section,` from your `\newtcolorbox` command. Or does your question refer to the list of boxes you show? What yould you expec there: "1.1 A mybox"  or "Box 1.1: A Mybox"?

Comment: Just rephrasing @leandriis comment: this is not a repetition, but the label contains the information on the section and the box counter. If you add a second box below the first one, it will have label `1.2`, and if you add a section and then a box, it will have label `2.1`.

Comment: If you want "Box 1.1: A mybox"  in your actual box and "1.1 A mybox"  in the list of boxes, add `list text={#2},` to your `\newtcolorbox` command.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, you're right. I meant it from another point of view.

Comment: @leandriis, I passed over that option in the documentation. Thanks for pointing that out. If at all needed, you can add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Joseph: I can surely add an answer, however I am still  a bit unsure which of my suggestions actually helped you achieve the desired output.

Comment: @leandriis, just adding `list text={#2}` did the trick.

Comment: @Joseph: so actually, my second assumption was the correct one. I have added an answer accordingly and also added an alternative if you want tp keep the "Box"  prefix in the list of boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove "Box 1.1:"  from the list of boxes and just stay with "1.1 A mybox"  there, you can use `list text={#2}` in the `\newtcolorbox` command.

[image]

If you on the other hand prefer keeping the term "Box"  in the list of boxes, you might want to use `list entry` as shown in the example below, instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage[lf,sfdefault]{FiraSans}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside=mybox]{mybox}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    title={Box~\thetcbcounter:~#2},
   % list text={#2},  %<----- Comment in for "1.1 A mybox"
   % list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2}, % <----- Comment in for "Box 1.1 A mybox".
    #1,
    halign title=center,
    sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,coltitle=black,titlerule=0pt,
    colbacktitle=lightgray,
    %colback=white,
    drop fuzzy shadow
}


\begin{document}

\tcblistof[\section*]{mybox}{List of boxes}

\section{Blá blá}

\begin{mybox}{A mybox}
That's it.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both options are great, thanks!